# How to fix the range of Volume in 2nd y-Axis

Tags: python, python-3.x, dataframe, matplotlib

My full code:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
plt.style.use('ggplot')
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

path = 'C:\\MyPath\\File1.txt'
dff = pd.read_csv(path, sep=",")
dff.columns = ['Date','Time','Price','Volume']
dff.plot('Time', ['Price', 'Volume'], secondary_y='Volume')
plt.show()
```

I have a price-volume DataFrame and I am using below syntax to plot `Volume` in the second y-axis.

```
dff.plot('Time', ['Price', 'Volume'], secondary_y='Volume')
```

My data in `Volume` column ranges from 0-500. When I am plotting it using the above syntax, the second y-axis takes the maximum and minimum of the `Volume` and adjust the range automatically.

I need to fix the bracket on second y-axis while plotting. I want the range of `Volume` as 0, 50, 100, 150, 200, 250, 300, 350, 400, 450, 500

Sample Data:

```
       Date        Time      Price     Volume
72612  31/01/2019  15:26:58  135.85    100
72613  31/01/2019  15:27:02  135.90    110
72614  31/01/2019  15:27:03  135.95    140
72615  31/01/2019  15:27:07  135.95    100
72616  31/01/2019  15:27:10  135.85    60
72617  31/01/2019  15:27:11  135.90    150
72618  31/01/2019  15:27:13  135.95    100
72619  31/01/2019  15:27:15  135.95    100
72620  31/01/2019  15:27:18  135.95    30
72621  31/01/2019  15:27:22  135.95    10
```

Sample image for more clarity

[image]

Comment: Since you are a new contributor on Stack Overflow, please read [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and [how do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: So you want to replace 20 by 50, 40 by 100, 60 by 150, 80 by 200 and so on on the right hand y axis?

Comment: Yes Sir, Need Fix range with gap of 50 in 2nd y-Axis

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to control/modify the secondary y-axis tick labels, I would use slightly different approach to plot: plotting one column at a time. Once you plot the secondary y-axis data, you can override the default tick labels by providing a list of desired tick labels. Based on the DataFrame you provided, following is one way to do it

```
# Read in your dataframe here

ax  = dff.plot('Time','Price')
ax2 = dff.plot('Time','Volume', ax=ax, secondary_y=True)

y_ticks = range(0, 501, 50)
ax2.set_yticklabels(y_ticks)
plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: But the Volume line is not plotting as per the new y-Axis. Like there is no value above 350 in volume but Volume line (Marked in Red).

Comment: @Rohit: I didn't understand the point. Please explain clearly. Currently the data plotted in my figure (orange line for Volume) is the **actual** data from your dataframe in the question. As you asked, I just modified the tick labels. So the ticklabel 50 in my figure actually means volume = 20 in the line. The ticklabel 100 is actually the data point 40 in your dataframe and so on. The reason there is no value above 350 in my answer is because the maximum volume in your dataframe you gave is 150 which translates to the highest y-tick label being 350.